# C# Application.ApplicationExit creates need to click 'X' twice

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

I have had a fairly thorough look around, but couldn't find anything related, so I have decided to ask here :)

I have created a WinForm in Visual Studio, and in its code it has a fair few functions. At this point its all working nicely. I then go and put
`Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);`
in the constructor function and when I go and click the little cross in the corner, I have to click it twice for it to close! I would put the code in here, but its 240 lines, so its kinda huge.. If you need to see it though, I can put it up.

Thanks in advance!
Dronnoc

Comment: Looks like mouse or keyboard problem. Do you see same behavior if you remove the ApplicationExit handler? Weired issue.

Comment: You should probably try figuring out what line is causing this before you post 200+ lines of code. Try commenting out lines until it no longer exhibits this behavior. You might also want to look for something like e.cancel=true

Comment: @HungryMind: I can safely say that its not a keyboard or mouse issue, if I create remove that line, it works nicely, but i need to run some code while the application is closing/closed.

Comment: @Conrad Fix: I am going through that process at the moment, shall report back when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it peoples!

I had a ListBox on the page, and a function running when the SelectedIndex changed. When i closed the form, it passed a SelectedIndex of -1, and then closed the second time. So, in order to fix it, I simply put some simple verification of the value on the ListBox function.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }

        void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

becomes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }  

        void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            //Rest of the code goes here.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ApplicationExit event is automaticly called on clicking the cross. So there is actual no need to call it. What do you want to do on closing?
If you want some action between clicking the cross and shutdown, you have to call the [FormClosing() event.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx)

Comment: Shall give the `FormClosing()` event a shot, will report back any results.

Comment: This failed too, shall now attempt Conrad Fix's suggestion in the original post's comments.